# Wordpress editor + qtranslate = span issue

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg, html

I am creating Wordpress multilanguage site and using qTranslate plugin for that. For inserting the content, every language has its own visual/HTML input field within Wordpress TinyMCE editor. The problem is that editor "eats" my `<span>` tags, such as auto-formats `<br>` and `<p>` tags!

Also, I tried TinyMCE Advanced, but with no effect. After saving the page/post, `<span>` tags just disappear from content. Does anyone knows what cause this problem?

Comment: how did you manage to get a seperate textfield for each language? Can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set `Spans` as [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements).